# Deploy a folder of GitHub branch to EC2 server using Capistrano

Tags: ruby-on-rails, github, capistrano3

I am doing my first server deployment. I am developing a **Rails** API project with **Angular** as front end. Server code is saved in a folder in **GitHub** branch. I need to deploy only the content of that folder into the server. Currently, in `deploy.rb`, I have given it as

```
set :repo_url, "https://url to the repository"
```

How can I specify the repo_url?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution. You can specify the sub folder name in the deploy.rb file as shown below

```
set :repo_tree, 'folder_name'
```

Thanks